# Return type std::optional<std::variant<...>>

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, variant

I have a situation where a function must return a value taken from a table.  A cell in this table (let's assume the table just works...) may contain a value, or it might not. This value can also be one of several types: `int, double, string, date` (but no other type).

What would such a function return? Is it a good idea to return `std::optional<std::variant<std::string, int, double, std::chrono::time_point>>`?

Would that be a good use of `optional` and `variant`?

Comment: sounds like optional + variant can solve this requirement.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would consider this to be a useful use of `std::monostate`. Specifically, `variant<std::monostate, int, double, std::string, std::chrono::time_point>`. `monostate` is useful for cases where a `variant` may not contain a value.

The nice thing about using an actual type rather than `optional<variant>` is that visitation works normally on it. You can write a functor that can take a `monostate` parameter, thus allowing you to use `visit` for even "empty" variants.

Comment: "Unit type intended for use as a well-behaved empty alternative in std::variant. [...]." Sounds about right. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate

Comment: optional<variant<...>> will be false if empty and true if it is occupied, which can be handy.

Answer (score 4):

Just want to add that before C++17 and the standardization of `variant` and `monostate`, there is already [`boost::blank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) to solve the exact same issue for `boost::variant`.

By convention, if `boost::blank` is used, it should always be the first template argument, so that a default-constructed variant is empty and checking for emptyness is done with `.which() == 0`.