# Would a template work for std::variant's visit?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, visitor-pattern

Earlier I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052934/return-type-stdoptionalstdvariant/44054930#44054930) about `std::variant`. Considering that the types hold by the variant are all printable by `std::cout`, is there a simple way to implement a visitor?

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) for example, all the way down you have several lambdas to cover each type, but all do the same thing (except `std::string`): `std::cout << arg << ' ';`. Is there a way to not repeat my self?

```
std::visit(overloaded {
            [](int arg) { std::cout << arg; },
            [](long arg) { std::cout << arg; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << arg; }
            // I removed the std::string case
        }, v); // v is the std::variant
```

and write instead:

```
   std::visit(  [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg; }, v);
```

or something like:

```
template<typename T>
void printer(T arg) {std::cout << arg; }
//.......
std::visit(printer, v);
```

Comment: The second block (with the generic lambda) should work.  The third block (with the template function) won't work because the template isn't a single function or object.  You could write your own callable with a template `operator()`: `struct printer { template <typename T> void operator()(T arg) { std::cout << arg; } }; std::visit(printer{}, v);` (which is roughly equivalent to the generic lambda).

Comment: When we keep adding the [tag:c++] tag to your questions, there's a reason. Please do it yourself from now on.

Answer (score 4):

No need to copy

```
std::visit(  [](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg; }, v);
```

this takes `arg` by (forwarding) reference.  I don't bother forwarding it; I don't care if it is an rvalue or lvalue really.

The template function doesn't work, because visit requires an object, and template functions aren't objects of functions; you cannot (yet) pass overload set names as objects in C++.

The `overload` trick is mainly when you want to dispatch different behavior.

One thing you can do is

```
template<typename T>
void printer(T arg) {std::cout << arg; }

std::visit([](auto&&arg){printer(arg);}, v);
```

or

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
   noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
   -> decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) \
   { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__(decltype(args)(args)...) )
```

then we get:

```
template<typename T>
void printer(T arg) {std::cout << arg; }

std::visit(OVERLOADS_OF(printer), v);
```

which creates an anonymous object that represents the overload set of functions named by the token `printer`.

Comment: You forgot the body of the lambda and you have an extra `)` after the first decltype.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with a `std::variant` having a `std::monostate` in addition to a a couple of different `std::vector<T>`s. Instead of overloading I solved it this way:

```
auto empty() const -> bool
{
    return std::visit([](auto arg) {
        // constexpr() does not work in a ternary operator...
        if constexpr(std::is_same<decltype(arg), std::monostate>()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return arg.empty();
        }},
        v);
}
```

Not the most elegant, but simple and might get you where you want.